# Reputation bounties by upvotes

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I don't think that the current implementation of reputation bounties is good. There is a good chance that after assigning a bounty to a question one doesn't receives any useful information at all and just wastes his/her hard-earned reputation. The bounty goes to the answer which is well-presented and obtained the most upvotes by other users, but it does not contain information which the bounty assigner really wanted. This is why I never use bounties.

I think that reputation transfer by bounty should be  solely decided by a bounty assigner. Upvotes by other users should not matter. Answerers receive reputation from upvotes and I think this is enough for them.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think this is a good idea. If it were to be implemented, we'll get a lot of complaints from authors who spent significant time solving the bountier's problems, wrote a clear answer, perhaps even got a confirmation from the bountier that it worked or got thanked by them, only to discover that by the time the bounty should've been awarded, the bountier is gone (permanently, or they just took a few days off). With the current automatic assignment, you have at least a chance at half of the hard-earned bounty.